# Unable to write shell history to a text file

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a shell with basic functions in C, operating through Unix. I'm having difficulty transferring an array of history commands to a text file.

History is stored as a pointer to an array, with a capacity of 20 as not to over-complicate things. I got the basis of the method online so I've tried to tailor it to my needs, however it just feeds a bunch of weird characters to the text file. 
Does anyone know why this may be happening?/What I could do to fix it?

I'm also not sure if the for loop is necessary.

Thanks in advance!

```
char *history[2];

void save(char ** history)
{
 FILE *f;
 f = fopen("history.txt", "w+");

 for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
 {
    fwrite (history, sizeof(history[i]), sizeof(history)/sizeof(history[i]), f);
 }

 fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest getting this working to the console with printf first, use a Debugger and you will notice problems with your pointer handling with history...(ie Remove the fwrite, and debug with the help of printf or sprintf)

Comment: Please make an [mcve] the use of pointers and the content of parameters is suspicious.

Comment: Print this within the function and check that it is what you expect: `sizeof(history)`.

Comment: `fwrite` is used to write *binary* data. Use `fprintf` if you want a text file.

Comment: You have `char *history[2];` but your loop is accessing `history[i]` for values of `i` up to 19. That can't be good.

Comment: @SergeBallesta one can use `fwrite` for text as `fwrite` doesn't care what kind of data you're writing, it's just a bit more tedious. `fprintf` indeed would be easier if any formatting is required or when dealing with C strings.

Comment: @lurker: **You** know how to do it, but my advice for a beginner is to keep things simple...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I agree `fprintf` or perhaps even `fputs` would be most appropriate here, for expert or beginner.

Answer (score 3):

> history

is a `char **`, which is a pointertype.

> history[i]

is `char*`, so still a pointertype

> sizeof(history)/sizeof(history[i])

always returns one, since all pointertypes shall have the same size.

So your write statement will print `sizeof(< anypointer >)` random characters.

**Solution**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    fwrite (history[i], sizeof(*history[i]), strlen(history[i]) + 1, f);
}
```

Notice: This will include the '\0' for each string.

Notice: This will write the internal state into the file, so you should consider to open it in binary-mode or to use:

```
fputs(history[i], f);
fputc('\n', f); /*or anything similar*/
```